# How to change the value of input using inc and dec function in ionic 3

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm getting the value from the rest-api in input field.

```
<ion-input name="inpval"  type="tel" id="idvalue"  class="inputvalue" [value]="tms.orderitem_quantity" maxlength="2">  </ion-input>
```

Now I need to change the value through increment and decrement function.

Note: **value get from rest api in loop.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-input name="inpval"  type="tel" id="idvalue"  class="inputvalue" [value]="tms.orderitem_quantity" maxlength="2">  </ion-input>
```

Use ng-model to bind the value whenever you get from api after that with functions modify it

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="inpval">  </ion-input>

after fetching data from api
this.inpval=xyz;

inc(){
//business logic
this.inpval=x;
}
dec(){
//business logic
this.inpval=x;
}
```